# Writing Realm Daos with closed transactions

Tags: java, android, realm, kotlin

We've started integrating Realm into our android project, and have encountered a small problem.
We've re-written our Daos with Realm, like this for example:

```
public class RealmAuthDao {

    public static RealmAuthToken getAuthToken() {
        Realm realm = RealmFactory.getAuthInstance();
        RealmAuthToken token = realm.where(RealmAuthToken.class).findFirst();

        return token;
}
```

but every few minutes got the the following exception -

"Unrecoverable error. Too many open files in io_realm_internal_SharedGroup.cpp"

We've realized that we need to close every realm instance we've opened throughout the application, so we tried this:

```
public class RealmAuthDao {

    public static RealmAuthToken getAuthToken() {
        Realm realm = RealmFactory.getAuthInstance();
        RealmAuthToken token = realm.where(RealmAuthToken.class).findFirst();
        realm.close // close the instance we were using

        return token;
}
```

However, when we did that, whenever we tried to access the members or properties of the objects we queried, it became invalid and the following exception was thrown:

“This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable.”

Is there a proper way to implement a Dao with realm? Or should we just query from a realm instance directly each time?

Answer (score 0):

What I do is that I get the instance of my realm object in my activity  and pass it to the dao class to make the query. Them close the instance after my activity stops and it works great, my dao methods are not static though so I need and instance of the dao and pass the realm object as a constructor parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you need to close the Realm instances, but you might want to [read the documentation on best practices regarding opening and closing them](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances)  - specifically that you should use `onCreate/onDestroy` for Activity/main thread and you should use a `try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {` block for background thread, and any method that needs to use Realm should have it passed as method argument.

```
public static RealmAuthToken getAuthToken(Realm realm) {
    return realm.where(RealmAuthToken.class).findFirst();
}
```